# puImportError: No module named pyexpat

Tags: python, modules

Whenever I try to launch 'hotot' I get this errors. This error also appears if i try something stupid in terminal along with "No Module named gdm"

```
 Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in    apport_excepthook
  from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 16, in <module>
 from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
 from pyexpat import *
ImportError: No module named pyexpat
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.04
python 2.7.3.
I found similar problem here https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug/issues/5 
but did not work.

as asked below I am inserting this too

```
ls  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
audioop.so  _codecs_cn.so       _codecs_jp.so  crypt.so    _ctypes_test.so         _elementtree.so  _io.so      _multibytecodec.so   _sqlite3.so
_bsddb.so   _codecs_hk.so       _codecs_kr.so  _csv.so     _curses_panel.so   _heapq.so        _json.so    _multiprocessing.so  _testcapi.so
  bz2.so      _codecs_iso2022.so  _codecs_tw.so  _ctypes.so  _curses.so          _hotshot.so      _lsprof.so  Python-2.7.egg-info
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/*/pyexpat*` in your question?

Comment: It says: No such file or directory.

Comment: One more thing: On which architecture and Ubuntu version are you? I can't reproduce the problem with a stock Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 Desktop.

Comment: Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation of python2.7 has been damaged; it [should contain `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/python2.7/filelist). The most likely cause is a misbehaving program, or a hard disk failure.

You can reinstall `python2.7` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

Comment: seriously I never ever ever imagined this could have been due to a hardware failure. reinstalling did the job. But still if I type some stupid command I don't get error "command not found" but rather I get "No Module Named gdbm" . It shows error with CommnadNotFound.py . I would be glad if you could help me fixing that too!. Thanks a lot

Comment: That looks like you need to reinstall `python-gdbm` as well.

Comment: you are a lifesafer :)